# Implement new Line Change on pressing "Enter" key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wysiwyg, contenteditable, execcommand

I am using `contenteditable` where I because of some business scenarios, I need to track the new line breaks `<br>`. To handle that, I did below steps:

1. On `keydown` event, I stopped "enter" key event (keyCode = 13)
2. On `keyup` event of "Enter", I fire `execCommand` as `$window.document.execCommand('insertHTML',true,'<br class="new">');`

It works like a charm unless I am at the line end.

#### Problem

- When the cursor is at the line end, first **enter** keypress inserts `<br class="new">` but line change of cursor do not happen although the `html` is inserted.
- When I press the **enter** again, nothing happens. No `innerHTML` is inserted.

[Here is the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RntSUaeqtjmGSl4QqzaZ?p=preview). Please check console to see the html

*It works perfect if there is any character before cursor*

I hope I have explained my problem clearly. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it seems like a workaround, but you can use `&nbsp;`

```
$window.document.execCommand('insertHTML',true,'<br class="new">&nbsp;');
```

It'll serve your purpose with a whitespace , which I think can be ignored.